# Prop comes null in script in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I send prop from my parent component to child which is item. Here is my child component:

```
<template>
   
        <div>
            {{ item }}
            <List v-else :elements="elements"/>
        </div>
        
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        item: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
            default: () => {
                return {
                    elements: [],
                };
            }
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.ListItems();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            elements: {},
        };
    },
    computed: {
        ListItems() {
            this.elements = this.item.elements;
        },
    },
    watch: {
        item: {
            handler(val) {
                if (val) {
                    this.elements = { ...val };
                } 
            },
            immediate: true,
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

So I am getting item in my template (here: {{ item }}) but I cannot use item in script. It comes null. Whats the reason for it? I believe it is because of vue lifecycle but I dont know how to fix it.